# Modificar Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Quisiera que `PQR-` se quedara constante o pegado al input y no se pueda eliminar

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><div class="row">Solicitud :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="solicitud" type="text" value="PQR-">
  </div>
</div>
```

Haci como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias poner el valor en un label.

Comment: Como haci me puede dar una explicacion mas grafica gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¿Qué te parece algo así? Pulsa en Ejecutar y escribe o borra el texto

```js
function rewriteText(){
  var text = document.getElementById('solicitud').value;
  var notPqr = text.substring(4, text.length);
  var result = "PQR-" + notPqr;
  document.getElementById('solicitud').value = result;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><div class="row">Solicitud :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="solicitud" value="PQR-" onkeyup="rewriteText()" onkeydown="rewriteText()" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta..!!

Comment: Gracias viejo me sirvio mucho eres un crack

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#solicitud').change(function() {
    var contenido = $(this).val();
    $(this).val('PQR-' + contenido);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><div class="row">Solicitud :</div></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="solicitud" type="text" placeholder="PQR-" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Podrías concatenarle ese `string` a lo que el usuario introduzca en el `input`.